# How to send HTML form data on email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have HTML form, and i want to send form data on my mail. I have validate form using jquery. Here's my HTML form

```
<form name="callBackForm" action="callback_email.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="callback-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div id="contact-form" class="form-container" data-form-container>
         <div class="input-container">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="full_name" data-min-length="4" placeholder="Full Name">
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
              <input type="tel" id="phone" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone Number">
              <textarea type="textarea" id="message" name="message" data-min-length="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              <div class="submit-row">
                  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-block submit-form">Submit</button>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

```
Here's my PHP code, but it doesn't work,

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['full_name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['telephone'];
        $msg=$_POST['message'];

        $to='xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
        $subject='Call Back Form Submission';
        $message="Name: ".$name."\n"."Phone: ".$phone."\n". "Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$msg;
        $headers="From: ".$email;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";            
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }

?>
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help you can provide!
What is the exact code to send an email in PHP?

Comment: I presume you not install and not configure your MTA (mail transfer agent) sendmail/exim/etc.

Comment: Please search your title before asking - it literally took me less than 10 seconds to find a duplicate